# How to find the values of $a$ and $b$ that make a function differntiable and continuous

Tags: derivatives, continuity, piecewise-continuity

I have a piecewise function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}-x^3-4x^2+10, & x <  -2\\ ax+b        ,&  x \geq -2\end{cases}$$

I need to find all the values of a and b that make $f(x)$ both continuous and differentiable at $x=-2$

I am confused how to go about solving this. what I did was plug the two equations equal to each other and got

$$2=-2a+b$$

Now I don't know what to do with this information. How can I proceed and finish the question?

Comment: You should do the same for the derivative of what you did for the continuity of the map.

Comment: The function must not "jump" at $x=-2$, hence you set the Pieces equal ; Likewise, the Derivative must not "jump", hence you should set those Derivative Pieces equal

Comment: The only possible problem is point $x=-2$, so you need to make function continuous and differentiable in this point. To do this, you need make $\lim_{x\to -2}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to -2}f'(x)$ to be equal for $x\to -2-0$ and $x\to -2+0$.

Answer (score 2):

We have a piecewise function:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
     -x^3-4x^2+10 \quad &x<-2 \\
     ax+b &x\geq -2 
    \end{cases}
$$
Notice that for $x<-2$ and for $x\gt -2$ the function is continous and differentiable, since it is the sum of continous and differentiable functions.

What about for $x=-2$? We want both the continuity and the differentiability of $f(x)$ at that point. Therefore, the conditions to be satisfied are:

- For continuity:
  $$
  f(-2)=\lim_{x\to -2^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to -2^+}f(x)
  $$
  that is $$-2a+b=2$$
- For differentiability:
  $$
  \lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(-2+h)-f(-2)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(-2+h)-f(-2)}{h}
  $$
  that is
  $$
  -3x^2-8x=a \\
  a=4
  $$

Therefore, we get:
$$
a=4, b=10
$$